# preg_match_all is only matching one

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the value after the dots, and I would like to get all of them (each as their own key/value).

The following is what I am running:

```
$string = "div.cat.dog#mouse";
preg_match_all("/\.(.+?)(\.|#|$)/", $string, $matches);
```

and when I do a dump of `$matches` I am getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .cat.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .
        )

)
```

Where item `[1]` is, it is only returning 1 value. What I was expecting was for it to return (for this case) 2 items `cat` and `dog`. How come `dog` isn't getting picked up by `preg_match_all`?

Comment: because the dot before the dog is already matched.. Use lookarounds to carry out this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lookahead:

```
\.(.+?)(?=\.|#|$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ8gR4/1)

Problem in your regex is that you're matching DOT on LHS and a DOT or HASH or end of input on RHS of match. After matching that internal pointer moves ahead leaving no DOT to be matched for next word.

`(?=\.|#|$)` is a positive lookahead that doesn't match these characters but just looks ahead so pointer remains at the `cat` instead of DOT after `cat.`.

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more what `?=` this does! Otherwise it's pretty fast answer

Comment: how far does the lookahead go? just one?

Comment: also do I need a lookahead for the `#` or does that do the lookahead for all 3?

Comment: Lookahead can be of any length pattern. And `(?=\.|#|$)` already looks ahead for `#`

Comment: It's a pattern matching lookahead - anything from `(?=` until the closing `)` is matched.

Comment: Yes in that case do use: `(?=[.#%@]|$)` for example.